# Text rewriting with learning of writing style

Tags: style-transfer

I do a lot of scientific writing in my job. Unfortunately, I often also have to rewrite amateurish text that some students write for manuscripts. They use tools like grammarly to fix grammar issues, but even after that, I find myself doing a lot of rewriting as grammarly does not catch all grammar problems, even introducing some in many cases. My postdocs are of limited use in this respect as their writing styles are not that great either. Importantly, I like the introduction and discussion/conclusions written in a particular way that maximizes their impact in terms of the arguments made. Can I train an AI (maybe GPT3 based) tool using my published articles (over 200 at this stage), figure out how I like to structure my papers, and then rewrite student submitted manuscripts to match that style, without changing the scientific content?

Comment: Don't write "A non-specialist's question...". If you're here, we know that you have a question. Please, just write your **specific question** in the title.

Comment: @nbro Thanks. I have edited the title.